# How can I add a volume bar?

Tags: jquery, html

HTML

```
<a id="mtoogle" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="www.xyz.com/uploads/speaker.png"></a>
<audio id="playTune" autoplay>
<source src="sound1.mp3">
</audio>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mtoogle').toggle(
function () {
document.getElementById('playTune').pause();
},
function () {
document.getElementById('playTune').play();
}
);
</script>
```

I found this code online.

1. How can I add a volume bar to this one button player?
2. I don't need the progress bar as it comes in default player.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="playTune" autoplay controls>
    <source src="sound1.mp3">
</audio>
```

Use "controls" in your audio (or video) deceleration.

Comment: Where are the controls?

Comment: Thank you. I had that actually. What I want to do is a) Remove the progress bar. 2) Put the music in loop. The only two things I need is a huge PLay Icon (Which I can do) and a volume bar. How can I do that?

Comment: In that case you  will need to hide the audio player, create divs styled to your needs, then use JavaScript to manipulate the play/pause and volume can be changed via: VideoElement.volume = 0.7;

Comment: This MDN article lists of the useful properties for a media element, which the audio element is derived from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement